Decomposing position time series to different IMFs using Empirical Mode Decomposition in Python
I am trying to decompose my signal ( the position time series ) obtained from MD simulation into the various modes by using Empirical Mode Decomposition. I want to be able to plot the velocity vectors corresponding to each mode at each time step of the simulation.
Can anyone tell me how I can extract the velocity vectors from the decomposed Intrinsic Mode Functions ? I am using the EMD module of python : enter link description here
